# Unable to deliver stream : error detected by clearacase subsytem

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am getting error while deliver operation for activity.
PFA screen shot for more details.

[image]

How would you avoid this error?

Transcript, for search purposes:

```
Unable to deliver stream "BMG_NONCE": error detected by ClearCase subsystem

ccweb: Warning: Please ensure that the target snapshot view "Nonce_deployment_intg" is up to date and free of hijacked files.
ccweb: Warning: The following activities contain only checked-out version:
   activity:Add_Payee_Mgmt@\BMB_PVOB
ccweb: Warning: These changes will NOT be included in this operation.
'mandacks" DOES NOT have permission to perform 'deliver_start- in project 'BMB_2.0@\BMB_PVOB'
Please contact your Project Lead if you need access.

ccweb: Warning: Trigger "Pre_access_control_BMB_PVOB_CVOB_Triger" has refused to let deliver_start proceed.
ccweb: Error: A deliver_start preop trigger does not allow this operation.
ccweb: Error: Unable to do integration.
Unable to deliver stream "BMG_NONCE": error detected by ClearCase subsystem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning are not blocking the deliver.

The trigger called 'Pre_access_control_BMP_PVOB_CVOB_Trigger' is.
You need to contact the ClearCase admin in order to see how the user `mandaoks` can be added to the exclusion list for that trigger, in order to not be blocked by said trigger.

Comment: @sakshi Great! Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer, for this answer and your previous ClearCase questions that you asked before.